# How to disable pkcs11 in gometalinter?

Tags: windows, go, lint

When unit test, or build my code, I have to use the following command:

`go test --tags nopkcs11`

I am using https://github.com/alecthomas/gometalinter on **windows** for linting.

The gometalinter works well, but whenever I run linting, I can see a large number (hundreds) of messages like this:

`c:\Users\xxxxxxxxx\workspace\go\src\github.com\hyperledger\fabric\bccsp\pkcs11\impl.go:70:24:warning: SessionHandle not declared by package pkcs11 (staticcheck)
c:\Users\xxxxxxxxx\workspace\go\src\github.com\hyperledger\fabric\bccsp\pkcs11\impl.go:70:24:warning: SessionHandle not declared by package pkcs11 (staticcheck)
c:\Users\xxxxxxxxx\workspace\go\src\github.com\hyperledger\fabric\bccsp\pkcs11\pkcs11.go:39:9:warning: New not declared by package pkcs11 (staticcheck)
c:\Users\xxxxxxxxx\workspace\go\src\github.com\hyperledger\fabric\bccsp\pkcs11\pkcs11.go:50:20:warning: cannot range over slots (invalid operand) (staticcheck)`

I run the metalinter in the following manner:

`$ gometalinter.v1 ./...`

Is there a way to disable *pkcs11* on gometalinter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of a hack + a windows user will have to have a unix terminal:

```
gometalinter.v1 ./... --deadline 10000000ms  | awk '!/pkcs11/'
```

Comment: Most Windows machines do not have a Unix terminal so this is likely of limited value to the asker.

Comment: au contraire, I would say most programmers working on windows machines do have a Unix terminal (Git Bash) and use it instead of the limitted windows cmd prompt

Comment: The reason why my approach is not good is that you shouldn't have to scan the unwanted files

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can use a [configuration file](https://github.com/alecthomas/gometalinter#configuration-file) for your project, per the `gometalinter` documentation. You can use the `Exclude` setting to set regular expressions that, if a message matches the pattern, the message will not be output.

Comment: can u pls improve the quality of this answer by providing a working example? (I can accept the answer afterwards, right now it's more of a comment)